# ASP.NET Core multi attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-core, attributerouting

In my ASP.NET Core Web API application, I have declared a route with multiple attributes like following

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{tenantId?}/user/getsettings/{id?}")]
```

When I made a request from swagger, the server is returning 404 not found.

```
http://localhost:5163/api/1/user/getsettings/2
```

Is this possible with .NET Core?

Comment: try without the `api` in the url

Comment: You may read this section for [more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis)

Answer (score 1):

Because your url actually not contains `api`. You can call url by using `http://localhost:5163/1/user/getsettings/2`. If you want to add `api` to your url you can add attribute to controller class by using `[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]`.

**Tip:** You can achive same config with only one `HttpGet("{tenantId?}/user/getsettings/{id?}")` attribute.